# Visual Studio's functionality to create an application for circuits

Tags: visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio. I want to create an application that would have GUI to add elements in the form of a ladder diagram. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: Since your new here I suggest your have a look at [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beckhoff TwinCAT 3. It will integrate in to Visual Studio and allow programming in all PLCopen (IEC 61131-3) programming languages. This includes ladder diagram (LD). You can even mix the languages as you like.

Please note that the base of TwinCAT is CoDeSys. It is not very comfortable for ladder.